# matplotlib render image with specs (size, alligment etc.) in pixels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have specs for a mockup, for example, Photoshop/Illustrator/Sketch file with each elements specifications like size, position, and coordinates in pixels.

An image looks like:

[image]

I can draw **similar** image just using standard *matplotlib* technic without any problems.

The question is, how to render an image **exactly** with its specs? All sizes, font sizes, alignments, should be the same as in the specs (as it's drawn in Illustrator).

I've researched over matplotlib docs, but even [transformers](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) tutorial doesn't help.

**Update** with an exact example.

I have a mock at Zeplin which shows coordinated of each plot (Image is also a plot here). So I know, that the image has margins 25x25px from a border and its size is 80x80 pixels.

[this is mock image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BFdK.png) (again not allowed to embed the image).

How would you do that?

The code I use for drawing

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10), sharey=True)

recs = ax[0].barh(y_pos, widths, align='edge');

img = mpimg.imread('/Users/iwitaly/Downloads/2017-11-12 17.40.46.jpg')

ax[0].spines['left'].set_visible(False);
ax[0].spines['right'].set_visible(False);
ax[0].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);
ax[0].spines['top'].set_visible(False);

ax[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(True);
ax[0].get_yaxis().set_visible(True);


obj = ax[0].text(x=0, y=3.9, s=r'Name: Vitaly Davydov',
          fontsize=30, fontname="Courier New", weight='bold');

ax[0].axhline(y=3.85, xmin=0, xmax=0.75, color='black');

# I'd like to place axicon exactly with 25x25 marging from top left corner
axicon = fig.add_axes([0.08, 1, 0.2, 0.2], transform=None)
axicon.axis('off');
axicon.imshow(img, interpolation='none');


for i, r in enumerate(recs):
    r.set_color(index_to_color[i]);
    r.set_height(col_wight);
    ax[0].text(x=0, y=text_positions[i], s=index_to_text[i], fontsize=30, fontname="Courier New");


ax[1].spines['left'].set_visible(False);    
ax[1].spines['right'].set_visible(False);
ax[1].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);
ax[1].spines['top'].set_visible(False);

ax[1].get_xaxis().set_visible(False);
ax[1].get_yaxis().set_visible(False);


ax[1].text(x=0, y=3.9, s='Increment:', fontsize=30,
           fontname="Courier New", weight='bold');

ax[1].axhline(y=3.85, xmin=0, xmax=0.4, color='black');

for i, r in enumerate(recs):
    text_x, text_y = r.xy

    increment_pos_y = text_y + col_wight / 2
    if increment_values[i] > 0:        
        increment_text = '+{}'.format(increment_values[i])
    elif increment_values[i] < 0:
        increment_text = '-{}'.format(increment_values[i])
    else:
        increment_text = '{}'.format(increment_values[i])


    ax[1].text(x=0, y=increment_pos_y, s=increment_text,
               fontsize=30, color=index_to_color[i],
               fontname="Courier New", weight='bold');
```

In this example I'd like to place **axicon** axes that is an image with 25x25 margin and 80x80 size (all in pixels).

Comment: It's sure possible to do this with matplotlib. The [transform](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) tutorial is indeed to place to start. For asking a question here, you would probably want to give an example including the code you have tried and clearly state at which point you have the problem. Otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you! I've added a code how I draw an image with exact question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place an axes to the figure, you can use `fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])`, where `left, bottom, width, height` are fractions of the figure size.

To convert from pixels to fraction of figure size, you need to divide the pixels by the figure dpi and the figure size. E.g. for the left edge

```
left = 25/fig.dpi/fig.get_size_inches()[0]
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 7))
y_pos, widths = np.linspace(0,3,4), np.random.rand(4)
recs = ax[0].barh(y_pos, widths, align='edge');

#img = plt.imread('/Users/iwitaly/Downloads/2017-11-12 17.40.46.jpg')
img = np.random.rand(80,80)

# I'd like to place axicon exactly with 25x25 marging from top left corner
x,y= 25,25 #pixels
dx,dy = 80,80
w,h = fig.get_size_inches()
axicon = fig.add_axes([x/float(fig.dpi)/w, 1.-(y+dy)/float(fig.dpi)/h, 
                       dx/float(fig.dpi)/w, dy/float(fig.dpi)/h])
axicon.axis('off');
axicon.imshow(img, interpolation='none');

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!